# I don't know why it can't this Error in my code

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I had a Problem with Node. I get an error(Cannot POST) when I press the Submit button. There is no problem even if I check with console.log. The executed value prints out fine in console.log.
I don't know why the error occurs.

View Page Code

```
...
{{#if search}}
 {{#each search}}
  <tr>
   <td>{{this.id}}</td>
   <td><a href="/boardRead?id={{this.id}}" class="readA">{{this.title}}</a></td>
   <td>{{this.name}}</td>
   <td>{{this.count}}</td>
  </tr>
 {{/each}}
{{/if}}
...

...
<form action="/auth/boardData" method="POST" class="left">
 <input type="text" class="form-control shortBox left" name="search" required>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary listHeight">검색</button>
</form>
...
```

Router.post Code

```
// For search
// 'auth/boardData'
router.post('/boardData', authController.boardData);
```

Controller Code

```
exports.boardData = async (req, res, next) => {
const { search } = req.body;

...
 if(search) {
  db.start.query('SELECT * FROM board WHERE title LIKE ? ORDER BY date DESC', ['%'+search+'%'], (err, result) => {
   if(err) console.log(err);
   if(!result) return next();

   console.log(result);
   console.log(err);

   req.search = result;
  });
 }
...
}
```

Router.get Code

```
router.get('/boardList', authController.boardData, (req, res) => {
    res.render('boardList', {
        search: req.search,
    });
});
```

Comment: "Cannot POST" isn't a standard error message with which I'm familiar.  Where specifically are you seeing this error?

Comment: Is your router mounted with the correct prefix - `/auth`? You did not provide the code that installs the router in your application.